# Server in App Config

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2, app-config, smo

```
<connectionStrings>    
<add name="System1.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=PC-1\Instance1;Initial Catalog=System1;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

I have this in my app config then use it in my application like this:

```
ConnectionStringSettings myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["System1.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString"];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (SqlConnection myDatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                myDatabaseConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand mySqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("someCommand")
{
mySqlCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}}}
```

I also have function that backup database

```
        Server myServer = new Server(@"PC-1\Instance1");
        Backup bkpDBFull = new Backup();
        bkpDBFull.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        bkpDBFull.Database = "System1";
        bkpDBFull.Devices.AddDevice(@"D:\Sample.bak", DeviceType.File);
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetName = "Sample";
        bkpDBFull.BackupSetDescription = "Sample";
        bkpDBFull.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(5);
        bkpDBFull.Initialize = false;
        bkpDBFull.SqlBackup(myServer);
```

My question is how I will add this `Server myServer = new Server(@"PC-1\Instance1")` in the app config?

Answer (score 2):

in your app config

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
       <add key="ServerName" value="PC-1\Instance1" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

then you can access it as

```
Server myServer = new Server(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString());
```